# Button on UIView does not respond unless I specify the correct CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to implement a simple UIView that will show at the bottom of the screen when internet connection is lost and will have a dismiss button. My UIView class looks something like this.

```
import UIKit

class ConnectionLostAlertUIView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    var viewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ConnectionLostAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ConnectionLostAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let bottomConstraint =     view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.bottomAnchor)
        let leftConstraint = view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.leadingAnchor)
        let rightConstraint = view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.trailingAnchor)

        viewConstraints = [bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(viewConstraints)
    }

    @IBAction func dismissButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Logger.log(message: "Dismiss button was pressed", event: .d)
        self.isHidden = true
    }
```

And I add this UIView to my UIViewController by doing the following

```
var ConnectionLostAlert: ConnectionLostAlertUIView!
ConnectionLostAlert = ConnectionLostAlertUIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
self.view.addSubview(ConnectionLostAlert)
```

Well, I can use actual values for CGRect instead of zero but the problem is that after the constraints are added in my UIView, the button in my UIView stops responding. It works just fine if I actually set some CGRect coordinates and not use constraints in the UIView. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve that will still allow me to handle the button event inside the UIView?

Comment: what are the set of constraints you are using to add the view to the viewcontroller?

Comment: All my constraints are set inside UIView`s didMoveToSuperview() function. I also added a height constraint since it was suggested byMilan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are adding constraints from the inner view i.e view to the superview skipping the main view (ConnectionLostAlertUIView) that is actually being added to the super view.

What you should do instead is to add constraints between view and self first. Then when self(ConnectionLostAlertUIView) is added to the superview, add the constraints with super view then.

Do something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
var viewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ConnectionLostAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let bottomConstraint =     view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
    let leftConstraint = view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor)
    let rightConstraint = view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor)

    viewConstraints = [bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(viewConstraints)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ConnectionLostAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let bottomConstraint =     self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.bottomAnchor)
    let leftConstraint = self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.leadingAnchor)
    let rightConstraint = self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.trailingAnchor)

    viewConstraints = [bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(viewConstraints)
}

@IBAction func dismissButton(_ sender: Any) {
    Logger.log(message: "Dismiss button was pressed", event: .d)
    self.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Awesome HAK, it worked. There is a little bug in your code (Pointing it out for future readers just in case). translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in didMoveToSuperview should be called on self instead of a view. Also, setting constraints for the view object was unnecessary in my case since I already set them up in .xib file. Basically, all I had to do was to set constraints on self instead of a view. Thank you so much for pointing that out.